# Nintendo 3DS built-in web browser sound via jquery

Tags: jquery, nintendo

I need a sound to play when commanded to in a website.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.ClickForSound').click( function() {
            //Play sound here

        });

    });

</script>
```

How do I get this, or something similar, to work to support the 3DS web browser?

Via JQuery is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a fair bit of lateral thinking, but one solution I found is to trigger the 3DS to produce the loading noise by reloading the page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.ClickForSound').click( function() {
            location.reload(true);

        });

    });

</script>
```

Hardly ideal.

Comment: Still hoping for a better solution than this hack